# @Autowired in FXML Controller

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I got a short question. I managed to do some dependency injections with a xml config file, it worked perfectly!
But once i try to inject into an FXML Controller it doesnt work anymore and i am getting a NullPointerException...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="iMainGUIHandler" class="de.vibrating_earth.main.MainGUIHandler" scope="singleton" autowire="byName"></bean>
<bean id="iMainModel" class="de.vibrating_earth.main.MainModel"  scope="singleton" autowire="byName"></bean>
</beans>
```

Injection Point

@Autowired
private MainModel iMainModel;

Answer (score 1):

Ok can be closed found the answer by myself  :)
I created the FXML Controller at runtime with "new", i added the FXML Controller has an singleton beans and now it does work!